# In C++, why am I able to initialize a private member class declared as const?

Tags: c++

In the following, isn't `_abc` already assigned a value (albeit a default one) of "", then it got changed to `"xyz"` when I initialize MyClass ?

Why is `_abc` being a `const` as declared in `MyClass`'s private member field not preventing it from being changed to `'xyz'` ?

```
    class MyClass{
        public:
            MyClass(const std::string abc);
            void doIt();
        private:
            const std::string _abc;
        
    };
    
    MyClass::MyClass(const std::string abc): _abc(abc) {} //are we not changing _abc from its initialized value ? But _abc is declared as const
    void MyClass::doIt(){
        std::cout<<"abc is "<<_abc<<std::endl;
    }
      
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;
    auto myObj = MyClass("xyz");
    myObj.doIt();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make `_abc` public and try to change it after the constructor call and you'll see that it is most definitely `const`. The constructor is initializing `_abc`, not changing it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not 'changed' to 'xyz'. When the constructor of `MyClass` is called, the initialization list initializes members. Therefore, `std::string`'s constructor is called with `"xyz"`, which is a valid call.

Comment: thanks, what about the original declaration of `const std::string _abc` , does that not assign _abc a value already ?

Comment: @user1008636 -- no, there is no assignment or initialization from the mere fact of declaring a member object. The constructor is responsible for initializing all the members.

Comment: It means that _if_ a constructor's member initializer list doesn't initialize `_abc`, `_abc` will be default-initialized. It doesn't prevent a constructor from doing something else, which your constructor does.

Comment: @user1008636 I think you're confusing _name_ with _value_. The `_abc` in `const std::string _abc` declaration is a name. It doesn't specify value; if you were to specify (default) value there, you'd write `const std::string _abc = "_abc";` there.

Comment: @lorro ah ok, so what instead of std::string, I do `const MyClass _abc`, where MyClass has a constructor (no parameter) defined, then in that case it'll actually assign _abc a value, right?

Comment: @user1008636 I don't know what you mean. `MyClass` cannot have a `const MyClass` member, that'd be recursive containment (class size would be infinite).